# ESP32 Websocket LED animation

Tags: animation, websocket, arduino, real-time, esp32

I am trying to use a ESP32 as a websocket server to receive animation frames for a WS2812 LED strip. I want the ESP to act as an output device so the data sent by a pc is displayed in real-time. Unfortunately i cant seem to get a smooth animation no matter what try. Messages are being clumped together and skipped so the frames are not consistent (same thing over a raw TCP/IP socket instead of websocket).

I have tried adding a buffer and a timer so the frames are displayed at a fixed interval but no significant improvements were made. Data was not being read or sent fast enough to keep the animation alive.

My questions are the following:
What is the logic i should follow? (Send data display when received, send data to buffer display on next frame, etc.)

Should i be taking another approach to this problem?

Below is an example ESP32 code that i used testing with 10 leds.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <FastLED.h>

// WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "myssid";
const char* password = "password";

// Websocket port
const uint16_t ws_port = 8080;

  AsyncWebServer server(80);
  AsyncWebSocket ws("/ws");
  AsyncWebSocketClient* wsClient;

// LED strip configuration
const int num_leds = 10; // Number of LEDs in the strip
const int data_pin = 23;  // Pin connected to the data input of the strip
CRGB leds[num_leds];      // Array of LED colors

// Array to store 360 chars
char chars[360];

// Array of corresponding colors
const CRGB colors[] = {
  CRGB::Black,  // 0 - off
  CRGB::Red,    // 1 - red
  CRGB::Green,  // 2 - green
  CRGB::Blue    // 3 - blue
};

void setup() {
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  // Initialize LED strip
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, data_pin, GRB>(leds, num_leds);
  // Start server and websocket

  ws.onEvent(onWsEvent);
  server.addHandler(&ws);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Update LED strip
  FastLED.show();
  delay(100);
}

// Websocket event handler
void onWsEvent(AsyncWebSocket * server, AsyncWebSocketClient * client, AwsEventType type, void * arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len){
  if(type == WS_EVT_CONNECT){
    wsClient = client;
    Serial.println("Connected WS!");
  } else if(type == WS_EVT_DISCONNECT){
    wsClient = nullptr;
  }else if (type == WS_EVT_DATA) {
    // Store incoming chars in the array
    size_t count = len < 10 ? len : 10;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      chars[i] = data[i];
    }
    //Serial.println("Received " + String(count) + " chars"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < num_leds; i++) {
      // Get the value of the char and use it to look up the corresponding color
      int value = chars[i];
      CRGB color = colors[value - '0'];
      // Assign the color to the LED
      leds[i] = color;
        
    }
    
  }
}
```

And some python code for sending test data:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def send_message(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri, subprotocols=["text"]) as websocket:
        while True:
            msg = ["0"] * 10
            for x in range(10):
                msg[x+1] = "1"
                msg[x] = "0"
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                await websocket.send("".join(msg))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send_message('ws://esp_ip/ws'))
```

Any help is apreciated! Thank you